# What I need to know before Learning Grails?

Tags: grails, groovy

I am a student now, and I like grails.

I have a bit experience with java, but not that much.

I know a bit of the java stack technologies

What technologies I should understand before going to developing websites with the Grails framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's worth knowing about the the technologies Grails is using under the hood:

- [Hibernate](http://www.hibernate.org/)
- [Spring](http://www.springsource.org/) (especially MVC)
- [Groovy](http://groovy.codehaus.org/)

It is also worth being familiar with the design patterns that Grails uses, in particular [model-view-controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller).

Some basic knowledge of [relational databases](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database) will also be useful.

Comment: Would you recommend me using this to build a not very complex web application, and plus learning a bit in the meantime.? I am also learning java. The website would be for a project, and hopefully also used by people?

Comment: @DaimanLocks, absolutely! using a technology to build something is a great way to learn how it works, and Grails makes this very straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

I would advise you to learn the Spring MVC Framework prior to Grails because Grails is based on this framework. So if you encounter an error you will have to check the stacktrace and understand what is going on.

You can start learning Spring MVC by reading [Introduction to Spring Web MVC framework](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html).

Comment: I was actually thinking to learn a bit of grail, then to transit to Spring. I thought it was easier that way...

Comment: Would you recommend this, for a personal web application, or should I go with a simpler solution like a php framework. Since I am not good at any language right now, but would like to learn java, and I am everyday...

Comment: Yes it's better to learn Spring before because Grails can be confusing if you don't know what's going on behind the scene. It's a good framework for your personal web site but more expensive to host (you need a Java host and they are not very common compare to PHP one).

Comment: Is grails only for enterprise solutions, and java enterprise developers? Or can it be used also for personal websites?

Comment: I would say yes it's more for enterprise size project but if you want to build something go ahead so that you'll learn the framework and Java.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried going through the [getting started guide for grails](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/gettingStarted.html)? that should get you going,  and you can pick up anything extra you need along the way...

Comment: Would you recommend it for a beginner, in the java enterprise world.

Comment: Is it just for enterprise, or can it be used also for personal web sites? Thanx

Comment: you can use it for whatever you want. no idea if you'll like it,  as that depends on your personal taste.  try it, try something else, try something else, pick your favorite.  the trick to software development is to keep trying new things, seeing where they might fit, and making up your own mind

Comment: Many say choose php for cheap hosting, is that an issue really? Can't seem to figure it out.